# simple question on html img tag

Tags: html, tags, image

does the filename in `src` attribute of an `img` tag has a limit in number of characters? or compatibility issue among operating system(OS) browsers...

for example:

```
<img src="../img/misc/this-is-a-very-long-image-filename-of-an-image-named-leaders-systems02.gif" alt="Leaders Systems" class="emblem" />
```

is there no issue on `this-is-a-very-long-image-filename-of-an-image-named-leaders-systems02.gif` in all OS browsers??

Comment: It may affect in the way its more human error prone :P typos always help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be bounded by [the maximum URL length per browser](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html).  The HTTP server may also send you an HTTP 414 "Request URI too long".  The standard does not dictate what this size is, but allows a server to make such a response.

From the [HTTP/1.1 standard S10.4.15](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.15):

> 10.4.15 414 Request-URI Too Long
>
> The server is refusing to service the
>   request because the Request-URI is
>   longer than the server is willing to
>   interpret. This rare condition is only
>   likely to occur when a client has
>   improperly converted a POST request to
>   a GET request with long query
>   information, when the client has
>   descended into a URI "black hole" of
>   redirection (e.g., a redirected URI
>   prefix that points to a suffix of
>   itself), or when the server is under
>   attack by a client attempting to
>   exploit security holes present in some
>   servers using fixed-length buffers for
>   reading or manipulating the
>   Request-URI.

Answer (score 2):

The full url to the asset can not exceed 2048 characters. See [HTTP URI GET limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there's an issue with long `src` attributes in any common browser. However, if you have lots of very long `src` attributes, it might affect the load time negatively.