# jquery.form gives errors with to much text

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

so i have  form that I am submitting via [jQuery form's ajaxSubmit](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit) it was working fine until I tried to put in text that is over 5100 characters long any idea why  this would be a problem ?

this is what shows up in the error console

Error: no element found
Source File: https://myebsite/
Line: 1

and this is that line

ok I found the problem but I don't understand why the name of the field was "summary" if I change it to anything else the problem goes away

**New Edit**

well this gets stranger changing the name only works until I save my js file then it breaks again.
also I Can't post this

```
  newteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststory
```

**BUT**
i can post this

```
 <p>
newteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststory</p>
```

which is just wrapping it in a paragraph tag wtf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out this was not related to jquery or the form plugin at all. The cause was a problem in my php related to a regex issue [answered here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263555/preg-match-breaks-with-more-then-5100-characters)

Answer (score 2):

It depends whether you're POSTing or GETing the form data.

Although there are no defined limits to a GET query your browser will perhaps set a limit and your server may not be able to handle something too large. Take a look at [Is there a limit to the length of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit) for more info.

If you're POSTing then it's more than likely to be a configuration problem on the server. Depending on what server software you're using you might be able to find a setting somewhere that allows users to POST larger amounts of data.

eg. In PHP you can set the `post_max_size = 8M` line in your `php.ini` file