# preg_match breaks with more then 5100 characters

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to match for plain text here is the regex

```
   $variable = "newteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststorynewteststory";
   $result = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}])+$/',$variable);
```

and it fails and I can't figure out why

Comment: I'd break too if I had to deal with a string that long...

Comment: You forgot a semicolon at the end of your first line.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer.

Comment: I missed the semicolon when I was copying

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams good poing 8 ^ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few suggestions to try:

1. Move the `+` inside of the capture group so it needs to do less internal shifting.

   ```
   $result = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}]+)$/',$variable);
   ```
2. Why capture at all?

   ```
   $result = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}]+$/',$variable);
   ```
3. Why not just negate so it doesn't need to build up the internal state:

   ```
   $result = !preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}]/',$variable);
   ```

What I think's happening is that you're over-running the internal buffer that pcre is using to keep track of the state.  Give a try using a negated preg match (since you're not using 
the captured group anyway, all you care is if it has an invalid character)...

And a nitpick: `$.+^()?<>*{}` don't need escaping at all inside of a character block. The only ones that do are your delimiter (`/`), `-` and a leading `^` character (which doesn't apply to you.

Comment: thanks for making my headache go away it looks much better now    $result = !preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#$.+\-%^&()~`\'":;_=?\/|<>*{}]/',$variable);

Answer (score 0):

You are matching too long text. It usually happen to me too when parsing very long subpatterns. Here are some things that you can try:

Remove the capturing parentheses:

```
$result = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}]+$/',$variable);
```

It might not work, as it still has to match very long text. Another way to do this is:

Do a negative match that matches only one character not in your set, and make sure that it does not match.

```
$result = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\r,!@#\$\.\+\-%\^&\(\)~`\'":;_=\?\\/\|\<\>\*\{\}]/',$variable);

$valid = !$result && strlen($variable) > 0;
```

P.S. Your code runs fine in my computer.