# storing an html in a variable php then echoing it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm storing an html in a php variable by using a `$_GET` method.
This is what I did.

```
http://myurl.com?html=%3Cdiv%20class=%22invoice-logo%22%20style=%22float:left;margin-bottom:15px;%22%3E%3Cimg%20src=%22https://myurl/account/images/invoice_logo.gif%22%20title=%22New%20Covenant%20Software%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22clear:both%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3Ch3%20class=%22invoiceNum%22%20style=%22padding:0px;font-size:25px;%22%3E%3Cstrong%3EInvoice#9368%3Cstrong%3E%3C/strong%3E%3C/strong%3E%3C/h3%3E%3Ctable%20class=%22widefat%22%20style=%22font-size:12px;margin-bottom:6px;width:48%;%22%3E%3Ctbody%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class=%22table_heading%22%20style=%22text-align:left;%22%3EBill%20To%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class=%22table_heading%22%20style=%22text-align:left;%22%3EContact%20Us%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left;background-color:white;%22%20class=%22table_body%22%3ETravis%20Harris%3Cbr%3ENew%20Covenant%20Software%3Cbr%3E322%20Old%20Mill%20Rd%3Cbr%3ENewmanstown,%20PA%2017073%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22text-align:left;background-color:white;%22%20class=%22table_body%22%3ENew%20Covenant%20Software%3Cbr%3E%3Cb%3E%28866%29%20213-6539%3C/b%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ca%20rel=%22noreferrer%22%20onclick=%22window.open%28%27https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&amp;fs=1&amp;tf=1&amp;to=billing@newcovsoft.com%27,%27Compose%20new%20message%27,%27width=640,height=480%27%29;return%20false%22%20title=%22[GMCP]%20Compose%20a%20new%20mail%20to%20billing@newcovsoft.com%22%20href=%22mailto:billing@newcovsoft.com%22%3Ebilling@newcovsoft.com%3C/a%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3C/tbody%3E%3C/table%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22float:right;margin-bottom:5px;%22%3E%3Cstrong%3EDate:%20%3Cspan%20class=%22dateCreated%22%3E12/01/2011%3C/span%3E%20%3Cspan%20style=%22color:#C5D0DD;%22%3E%20|%20%3C/span%3E%20Due%20Date:%20%3Cspan%20class=%22dueDate%22%3E01/01/2012%3C/span%3E%3C/strong%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22clear:both;%22%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20id=%22table-invoice-result%22%3E%3Ctable%20class=%22widefat%22%3E%3Ctbody%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EQuantity%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3EDescription%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3ERate%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3EAmount%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E8%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3EROSS%20Server%20Fees:%20TESTING3%20%28December%2016th%202011-January%2015th%202012%29%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E$79.99%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E$639.92%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E12%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3EROSS%20Server%20Fees:%20TESTING3%20%28December%2016th%202011-January%2015th%202012%29%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E$79.99%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E$959.88%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E10%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$799.90%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E1%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;text-align:left;%22%3ECustomer%20Credit:%20Server%20Fee%20Credit%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=%22background-color:white;%22%3E%3Cfont%20color=%22RED%22%3E-$79.99%3Cfont%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/font%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3ESales%20Tax%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class=%22salestax%22%3E$0.00%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3Cstrong%3ETotal%3C/strong%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class=%22total%22%20style=%22font-weight:bold;%22%3E$0.00%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20class=%22date_paid_status%22%20style=%22font-size:%2020pt;%20color:darkblue;%20font-weight:bold;%22%3EPAID%2012/01/2011%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%3E%3C/td%3E%3C/tr%3E%3C/tbody%3E%3C/table%3E%3C/div%3E%3Cbr%3E%3Ci%3E*%20Paper%20Checks%20are%20not%20accepted.%20Any%20paper%20checks%20received%20will%20be%20converted%20into%20E-Checks%20and%20destroyed.%3C/i%3E
```

My problem is if I try to echo this one, I'm not getting all the result. This is how I echo it.

```
$html = <<<EOD
{$_GET['html']}
EOD;
echo $html;
```

This are only the results I have when I echoed this:

```
<div class="invoice-logo" style="float:left;margin-bottom:15px;"><img src="https://myurl/account/images/invoice_logo.gif" title="Test Title"></div><div style="clear:both"></div><h3 class="invoiceNum" style="padding:0px;font-size:25px;"><strong>Invoice
```

As you can see, it cuts off after the code `<strong>Invoice`

 Any ideas why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you pollute a query parameter with this much junk rather than just `post`ing?

Comment: will it solve my problem if I'll use POST method?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html and [Is there a limit to the length of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit)

You're much better off using `curl` to get the contents of the URL in PHP (if you're trying to get the HTML from a standard website), or using `POST` (if you're passing the HTML into the PHP file directly).

Answer (score 4):

You are doing something wrong.
HTML is a part of the program code, and shouldn't be sent to and fro between server and client.

Instead of that, only raw *data* should be recieved from client, then formatted on the server side and then resulting HTML have to be sent to client.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the html to be inside a GET request, use base64_encode(). After submitting it, you can decode the html by running base64_decode($_GET['html']).

Comment: I don't see how this is any better than URL-encoding.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL `url_encode` is ambiguous and doesn't always work as expected. E.g. does it replace a space with `%20` or `+`..? And which is the preferred..?