# Upload file with php and ajax without using the usual form post method

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, file, upload

i'm trying to upload a file with php. The usual process is:

form `POST->php`

But i'm using this method:

`form->button` with `onclick` event that calls ajax/javascript `function->ph`p script call from javascript

I'm passing the full form (this.form) to javascript, javascript do some stuff and send all the form inputs one by one to php using `GET (xxx.php?xxx=xxx&yyy=yyy....)`, one of those inputs is a FILE , and I don't know how to send it to the PHP script trough javascript function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't send a file by GET, just use POST, second you need a flash uploader for < IE 8 and for other browser you need an iframe. There is no other solution that i am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML 5 File API to upload file via JS ([here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) is nice tutorial). But you must be cautious, because server may have max URI length limit (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit) for more detail).