# Pass an PHP Object or Array from one Site to another Site?

Tags: php, parameter-passing, xml-rpc, json-rpc

In PHP, how can I pass an Object (actually an Array) from one Site to another Site (by not losing its original Object Structure and Values)?

- How to PASS/SEND from the host site
- NOT to pull from the destination site

I want to pass directly from the automated script by NOT using `HTML` and web forms.
Any suggestion, please.

Comment: Are you asking HOW to do it ? Or how to encode variables (e.g [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) or [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize)) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do that is to use `json_encode()`:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/script.php?data='.json_encode($object));
```

on the other side:

```
$content = json_decode($_GET['data']);
```

or send it using cURL

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/script.php';
$post = 'data='.json_encode($object);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

on the other side:

```
$content = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: updated my question, also please. I'm not getting. I want to send.

Comment: you are calling that URL, it doesn't matter if you don't want to get.

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is the one ;) This combination of `json_encode` + `json_decode` + `cURL` is an amazing remedy.

Comment: its helpfull by using json for small data. but if the data size bigger that 70MB then it will be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to JSON and then convert it back to the PHP object. This is very easy when it is an array. You can just use `json_encode($array)` and `json_decode($json)`on the other site. I would send the data via POST because the limit length of GET: [Is there a limit to the length of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit)