# Javascript: Is there a simple way to pass data from one webpage to the other?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one .html file where I click some checkboxes and store some data on an array.

All I need is to pass the array data to one other .html file.

Searching on Stack Overflow I found some answers, for example ["How to pass JavaScript object from one page to other"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709289/how-to-pass-javascript-object-from-one-page-to-other).

From what I figured out one way is to use Web Storage API and specifically the [Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. Or simply use `JSON.stringify(obj)` to get a string representation to pass in your querystring to the other page. The other page can then use `JSON.parse()` to get it back into an object. You may need to escape/unescape as a URL encoded string too. In any event, this is all quite simple to learn :)

Comment: Mentioning your own deadlines is not the best approach since it will turn potential answerers away. `localStorage` is a very simple API. Try it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509089/passing-data-from-one-web-page-to-another?lq=1 or submit a GET form and access the querystring on your target

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass javascript object from one page to other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709289/how-to-pass-javascript-object-from-one-page-to-other)

Comment: You could also use `location.hash` for this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509089/passing-data-from-one-web-page-to-another/66557503#66557503

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using basic HTML and querystring manipulation without using localStorage or sessionStorage, although these are actually very simple APIs and worth looking into.

**HTML1 (sender):**

This page will get the string representation of an object and then escape its content for transport in the query string.

```
<script>
var obj = { givenName: 'John', familyName: 'Doe', age: 45 };
console.log(obj);
function passToNextPage() {
    window.location = 'test2.html?' + escape(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
</script>
<button onclick="passToNextPage();">Pass</button>
```

**HTML2 (receiver):**

This page unescapes the querystring and then parses the JSON text as an object, ready for use.

```
<script>
    var json = location.search.substring(1);
    json = unescape(json);
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(obj);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Localstorage is very simple - go for it. *Only catch is that it saves the data on the user's own computer so it is (a) not available to other users, and (b) able to be seen with the right tools.*

Another option, though, is to use a `<form>` - that's what they're for.

**page1.html**

```
<form action="page2.html" action="get">
    Name: <input name="thename" type="text" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send It" />
</form>
```

In `page2`, to get the data from the first page, you can either use PHP (which means your page would be named `page2.php` and begin with `<?php //php code here ?>` or with Python or some other backend language.

For more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

From your question, I think Localstorage will be a good option.