# Huge data string passing in url

Tags: javascript, url, parameter-passing

I have created a html page which has a div displaying image.I have to pass the  base 64 image string into this html page in the url so that I can set the image div source on loading.

The html page can be called from any application may be java/javascript or any.But along with the url the image string has to be passed to the page. Here is the sample html application which calls my html page-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
imagestring ="R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7";
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="window.open('URL?image='+imagestring)">open the html page </button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here URL points to the html page deployed on a server.This works fine only if the imagestring value is small.
But if the size is huge because of the limitation on several browsers it won't work.What alternate way I can approach?

My requirement is huge datastring passing in url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to POST the image data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

  <form action="URL" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="image" value="R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7"/>
   <button type="submit">open the html page</button>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I never worked on http request /response.I have tried posting the image string value to the html page as above posted by Qwerky ..But not getting how I can use this imagestring value in the html page?

Comment: Or in other words how can I get the imagestring value in the html page which is pointed by the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Standard URLs which use `GET` method by default have a limit of about 8KB in length.

If you want to send large data to the server, you must use `POST` method. In this case, URL remains short, and actual data will be sent to server as parameters in your submit form.

You can also POST data using ajax, [like this](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET method to passing your data.
 you can't pass huge data by GET method. check this out: [HTTP URI GET limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit) 
Use **POST** method.