# Function doesn't work with long input parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Below function works when the input string (#txtarea) contain few characters but doesn't work when it contain long string, how to get it working?

below is my code:

```
 $('#insertcmt').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/InsertComment?callback=?', { commenttext: $('#txtarea').val() }, function (data) {
        });
        loadcomments();

    });
```

server side logic:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public void InsertComment(string commenttext)
    {
        string sql = "INSERT statement";
        Database db = Utilities.GetDataBase();
        DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sql);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
    }
```

Is it because i am trying to access from Cross Domain?

Comment: you need to show your server logic and some examples of when it work and when it doen't

Comment: Are you properly escaping the string to be used in a url?

Comment: @w.brian What you mean by escaping?

Comment: This function escapes text
var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long URL (over 2000 characters) may not work in all web browsers.

Use a POST method:

```
$('#insertcmt').click(function () {
  $.post('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/InsertComment?callback=', 
    { commenttext: $('#txtarea').val() }, 
    function (data) {

    });

  loadcomments();
});
```

Edit:

You'll have to change the [WebGet] attribute to:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: @Khan You have to change the atttribute [WebGet] to [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]

Comment: I change to     [WebPost(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] but its not recognising WebPost

Comment: @Khan I've edited my comment, it should be [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by the limitation in the RFC GET request. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit).

Since you are using an insert statement in your serverside logic, you should probably use a POST request anyways.

```
 $('#insertcmt').click(function () {
    $.post('http://localhost:55679/RESTService.svc/InsertComment?callback=?', { commenttext: $('#txtarea').val() }, function (data) {
    });
    loadcomments();
});
```

Comment: @Khan: Maybe that is caused by a cross-domain request. A common solution is using jsonp. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3506306/473475) for details on this :)
However, this might also be a serverside issue. I am not an asp developer, and I don't really know how to debug this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the content via POST, rather than a GET, there's no universal limit in theory.