# jQuery Mobile getJSON base64

Tags: jquery, mobile, base64, getjson

I have problem with getJSON that sending huge parameter like sending image with base64 encode to server.

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("upload.php/?jsoncallback=?",
{
    "images" : "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"
},
function (data) {
    alert (data.success);
});
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: So, this doesn't work?  This is on a mobile site, so on a cell phone?  Do you get any errors?  Anything in your console?  Do you see the JSONP call in your dev tools?  Does your server send back the correct (JSONP) response?

Comment: this is web app on my local computer, and i using firebug to debug my code. when i click my button with that code, then nothing happen.

Comment: Why are you sending a base64'd image as a `GET` parameter?  That's probably your issue.  My guess is that the URL you are trying to load is too long.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/417184

Comment: may be that's why my code not running.. I using getJSON because it's simple to get response from server with json object. Any other solution?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  You want to upload an image to your server, then get back JSON?  Is the server on the same domain as the page?  If so, I'd suggest using `POST` instead.

Comment: Ok, I'm try using POST and that's work. Thanks Rocket Hazmat..

Answer (score 0):

HTTP `GET` requests have size limitations. It's best to use `POST` to submit the base64 data, as several folks have already commented.

As stated [in this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/http-uri-get-limit) it's probably safe to have up to 2,000 characters, which is an IE implementation limit, not a spec limitation.