# Call PHP without posting or submitting a form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post

I am building a website that may let users store data offline and then upload them when online. The offline data are stored in the indexedDB built inside the browser. The data amount can be huge, especially when users type in very long paragraphs and even uploading attachments (encoded as base 64 strings). When the users connect to the internet, they need to upload the offline data to MySQL database. Suppose they have an array of objects to upload, and each object may contain data string longer than the allowable URL limit. The only solution I know is to submit a form for each object. Because posting to a PHP file with URL parameters will exceed the URL limit. I am wondering:

1. is it possible to upload object array ( > 100MB) by clicking one button? It's better not to submit forms because of the large number of objects;
2. if PHP cannot do this, how about C#?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible if you use SOA or REST

Comment: Something like [jQuery form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or C#, the upload size limit is a server configuration, and both POST and GET requests can be done with ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit can be modify via server for both `GET` and `POST`, You should use the Post verb when you are going to store information for best practice, the POST verb by default doesn't have limit. So this is you way to go.

I think what you have to do is use an `AJAX`post. and use `JSON.stringify` to send all your javascript object in text form, then you can parse the json object in PHP or C# without any problem.

best

This question can also help you.
[.net webapi HttpGet vs HttpPost. why HttpGet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901944/net-webapi-httpget-vs-httppost-why-httpget)

Answer (score 0):

You should try increasing the Php limit from the php configurations in php.ini

increase the `max_upload_size` and `max_file_size` parameters as per your requirement. Php can handle long uploads.

I would suggest the following, compile a file or a series of files to be uploaded to the server instead of pure data. Would help the upload be more stable, you can find quite a few jquery php file uploading modules.

Once the file is uploaded extract the contents out of the file and remove the data from the offline DB.