# How do I change maximum length of HTTP GET request to store the params ? Is it possible?

Tags: php, html, get, maxlength

Hi I want to increase the size of the params (in URL) via HTTP GET request.

My requirement is,  I am modifying a html form which is already built with few fields and the type of form request is "GET" to add another description field to it. the length of the description may be several lines. If I send this data also via GET, there may b e a chance of exceeding the limit of the total URL limit. SO as a measure of precaution I am trying to increase the GET request size.

Is it possible? if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search returned this question:
[Is there a limit to the length of a GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request)

To conclude: in specifications no limit is set for GET request size, but some web browsers set limits (for example, IE, which limits the GET request size to about 2000 characters). Also, from my own experience I know that some web servers (like Apache) allow to configure the maximum GET/POST request size, but this depends on which web server You are using in the backend.

Suggestion: use POST instead of GET, if You need to have bigger request size than 2000 characters. Verify whether Your web-server sets limits to GET/POST request sizes or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your current URL is like your website.com/index.php?something=hello you can add more params by doing index.php?one=1&two=2&three=3 you can call it in the same way using $_GET['one'] or $_GET['two']

Comment: Accurate, but useless in the context of the question asked. Chella already mentioned that there is more than 1 param in the form. - "form which is already built with **few fields**"