# Unexpected end of input : Spring + Jackson + Json

Tags: json, spring, tomcat, jackson

I am using spring framework. From a jsp page I am doing an ajax call which gives call to a controller written using spring framework. From this ajax call a json is passed as controller parameters.

**I guess** that if the json is small then everything is working fine but if the json length increases then I am getting following exception in the tomcat -

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING  at
>   [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@147fb5c4;
>   line: 1, column: 6454794]; nested exception is
>   org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected end-of-input in
>   VALUE_STRING  at [Source:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@147fb5c4; line: 1,
>   column: 6454794]

**Above exception is not coming every time for a big json. In the brower console & also in the network tab I am not getting anything(so not able to capture the json).**

can some one please help me out in understanding what may be the cause for this issue & how to resolve this. Its really difficult to debug this scenario as its not always getting reproduced.

Comment: Ok, color me intrigued. What do you need a 6.5M character JSON response for? Is it returning the text of an entire book to be shown in a single page?

Comment: Are you sending the request to the controller via "GET" (which will have length limits)?  Have you tried "POST" (which should not have limits)?

Comment: @t0mppa yeah i am unable to figure out why this big json is going as response. I am unable capture the json when this exception is occuring can u please tell me a way so  that i can capture that json. As its not happening all the time its getting difficult to figure out why this big json is going as response

Comment: Please read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request -- whatever browser you are using, I wonder if you are hitting the GET limit for some of your requests.

Comment: @DavidFleeman oh sorry in the previous comment i used not... :)
i am using POST to send the request to the controller...i have deleted my previous comment.

Comment: Even if this big(6.5M) json is there in response, is there a way to process this kind of json. I mean to say this should not throw the exception as I am using post request and there is no limit set for the POST inside the tomcat server

Comment: If it's way too big, then how about debugging the creation of said JSON? What kind of code is causing it to bloat so much?

Comment: @t0mppa yeah at the first place json should not be so big...i will find out the reason which part of code is causing the json to bloat so much..