# How to create a tracking script similar to Google analytic with js and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a tracking script. Something similar with Google Analytic but very basic.

The requirements are

I need simple js script like Google Analytic does
make most of the logic inside the js file from the main site
collect in PHP the information and store it
What I can't figure yet is what are the ways to do this? Google from what I see is loading a gif file, stores the information and parses the logs. If I do something similar sending the data to a php file Ajax cross site policy will stop me, from what I remember.

Comment: if the javascript is on your server, and it is sending data to another server, nothing will stop you.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure on how Google Analytics does things, but the way to circumvent the x-site policy is, simply, don't do an Ajax call. Suppose you used javascript and now have an hash with your visitor's data:

```
var statsPage = 'http://mysite/gather_stats.php';
var stats = {
    page: location.href,
    browser: 'ie',
    ip: '127.0.0.1',
    referral: 'google.com?search=porn'
};
var params = $.param(stats); // serializes it https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/
```

now you only have to do a GET request to you php page with this string as a parameter, don't use Ajax tho, simply use the url as an `img` src

```
$('<img>', {
    src: statsPage + '?' + params
}).appendTo('body').remove()
```

you may as well use a `script` tag the same way, but you should pay attention because anything the php stats page returns will be executed as javascript (which is exactly how `jsonp` works).

Bear in mind that some [limits apply to Get strings length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request).

Comment: Like this answer, both funny and simple to understand. Why did you add this `.remove()` after you appended the image to the <body>? Does the image have to be removed or is it just because the url is not an image?