# saving an XMLDocument object created in javascript on the server using php

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I changed an XMLDocument localy using javascript. How do I save it on the server? I tried the following:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{ // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","./path/to/phpfile/file.php?newdocument="+newxmldocument,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

In the php-file I wanted to do something like this:

```
$file = "./path/to/xmlfile/xmlfile.xml";
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom = $_REQUEST['newdocument'];
$dom->save($file);
```

This does not work, however.

Is there an easy way to save the XMLDocument object the php-file recieves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try sending the XMLDocument with a POST as a multipart.

Comment: Do you mean using "POST" instead of "GET"?

Comment: Yes! Please read about the limitations of GET method and POST method.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request

Comment: Ok, so I changed that to POST, put the data into the send method, and changed the php-file to use POST, too. Setting $dom=$admin returns an fatal error, though, when using $dom->save($file), namely "Call to a member function save() on a non-object".

Comment: I also added this: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: add a var_dump to the php file. Post here what it prints.

Comment: The output of var_dump simply is "string(20) "[object XMLDocument]""

Comment: could the error be in the javascript part? If so, I'll update the question to represent what is done there...

Comment: I solved the problem. I ended up converting the xml-object to a string with XMLSerializer in javascript and using ->loadXML in php. Thank you for your help, it was exactly the input that I needed :)

Comment: glad to help! Now please post the final solution so that others can find it easily. Cheers!