# Why does Django's URLField truncate to 200 characters by default?

Tags: python, django, url, django-models, orm

I'm fond of Django and use it regularly. I find most of its defaults sane, but one has always bothered me to the point that I override it on every project.

The default max length of a [`URLField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2299) model field is 200 characters.  The docs verify this limit, but don't explain why it is the case.

```
class URLField(CharField):
    ...

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = kwargs.get('max_length', 200)
        ...
```

I override it because plenty of URLs are longer than 200 chars, especially with a query string.

I understand that though the HTTP spec [does not specify a maximum length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request/266345#266345), virtually all browsers support [at least 2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/149428), which to me suggests a new sane default.

Curious to dig deeper, I found the first commit to add the limit in January 2007 (#`f6390e8` by @jacobian); it's been essentially unchanged since.

[https://github.com/django/django/blob/f6390e8983dd364053078cc80361cb369b667690/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L805](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f6390e8983dd364053078cc80361cb369b667690/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L805)

Going back even further, I discovered what I think is the version of the code mapping field types to database column types for the ORM (`#f69cf70` by @adrianholovaty).  The file for MySQL for example exists in May 2006 with the same 200-character limit since Django 0.95:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/f69cf70ed813a8cd7e1f963a14ae39103e8d5265/django/db/backends/mysql/creation.py#L28

Comment: "plenty of URLs are longer than 200 chars" Which studies have you based this on?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I haven't referenced a particular study, just something I've experienced practically -- one case was building an app with a social feed that saved expanded URLs from tweets.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams if only one url is longer than 200 chars, it is enough reason to say that 200 chars isn't enough.

Comment: @Taylor Edmiston - can you provide a direction on how to override the setting.  I am running into this issue.

Comment: @MikeF Sure, you can override it like this: `URLField(max_length=1000, ...)`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say why the original max length was chosen, you would have to ask the authors of the patches you found. Note that [MySQL restricts unique var chars to 255 characters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#notes-on-specific-fields), so choosing 200 avoids this problem.

Once the limit was chosen, changing it would have backwards compatibility issues. Since migrations were added in Django 1.7, it would be easier to make a change like this. If you feel strongly about changing it, the Django developers mailing list or ticket tracker is probably a better place to ask than stack overflow.

You might find the discussion on [ticket 19515](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19515) interesting.