# DJANGO OPENCENSUS url field in request data too long

Tags: django, appinsights, opencensus

I am having a similar issue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65189698/django-celery-wsgi-dropping-telemetry) since adding App Insights to my application.  It may be related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214037/why-does-djangos-urlfield-truncate-to-200-characters-by-default) also, but neither of them are directly related to App Insights and neither have solutions.

This is the error from the django-tasks.log

```
Data drop 400: 100: Field 'url' on type 'RequestData' is too long. Expected: 2048 characters, Actual: 3701 {'iKey': <uuid>, 'tags': {'ai.cloud.role': 'manage.py', 'ai.cloud.roleInstance': <instance>, 'ai.device.id': <device>, 'ai.device.locale': 'en_US', 'ai.device.osVersion': '#1 SMP Tue Aug 25 17:23:54 UTC 2020', 'ai.device.type': 'Other', 'ai.internal.sdkVersion': 'py3.6.12:oc0.7.11:ext1.0.4', 'ai.operation.id': 'fcbe18bf6ca9036aa4546af171f3e877', 'ai.operation.name': 'GET /<my_url>/'}, 'time': '2020-12-15T17:58:36.498868Z', 'name': 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Request', 'data': {'baseData': {'id': '116a0658b513bdb9', 'duration': '0.00:00:00.096', 'responseCode': '200', 'success': True, 'properties': {'request.name': 'GET /<my_url>/', 'request.url': 'https://<my host>/<my_url>/?<my very long query string>', 'django.user.id': '90', 'django.user.name': '100044505'}, 'ver': 2, 'name': 'GET /<my_url>/', 'url': 'https://<my host>/<my_url>/?<my very long query string>', 'source': None, 'measurements': None}, 'baseType': 'RequestData'}, 'ver': 1, 'sampleRate': None, 'seq': None, 'flags': None}.
```

We also see this repeating in the logs.

```
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
Queue is full. Dropping telemetry.
```

I could rewrite the app to use shorter queries, but that seems like the wrong answer.  Is there a way to configure django to support long URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer cannot be changed, but you  can limit the size of the URL with a filter. In order to customize the trace exported, it has to be instantiated separately.

```
def shorten_url(envelope):
if 25 < len(envelope.data.baseData.url):
    envelope.data.baseData["url"] = envelope.data.baseData.url[:25]+"..." 
return True

from opencensus.ext.azure.trace_exporter import AzureExporter
exporter = AzureExporter(service_name='mysite')
exporter.add_telemetry_processor(shorten_url)

OPENCENSUS = {
    'TRACE': {
         'SAMPLER': 'opencensus.trace.samplers.ProbabilitySampler(rate=1)',
         'EXPORTER': exporter
     #Assumes Environmental Variable 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
    }
}
```

Complete working example:
https://github.com/Gamecock/Django-appinsights-example