# can we use POST in place of GET in rest service

Tags: rest, post

Why cannot we use GET instead using POST method in rest service,ignore what exactly POST does(creating new data/records).

Answer (score 0):

There could be different answers that your interviewer was looking for, two that I came up with:

- This is a convention that you use POST to create, PUT to modify, GET to get and DELETE to remove. And we should follow conventions.
- browsers support GET not POST, so if it's a service which is called by the browser - you can't use POST (it's not totally accurate, because the browser uses javascript which supports POST - but you get the gist of it).

That said, your application may not follow convention and use POST to get information and GET to create a new entity and etc. It's going against good practice but it's possible to do, so asking "why can't we use POST" is wrong because we *can* use it if that's what we want to do...

By the way, the other way around is not symmetric: GET is limited with the [length of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266322/is-there-a-limit-to-the-length-of-a-get-request) so while POST may send a huge payload, GET might not be able to send the same amount of data!